# Separating MySQL content via PHP on a "per-country/user preference" basis

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I'll lay this out simply:

I have one database that has content in it but I need to set up a conditon where if the user has selected Britain instead of the U.S. or vice versa -- some content will not show. This condition can be applied via a checkbox in the backend like so.

"Hello, I'm a paragraph" show in [x] Britian [x] U.S.

I'm not looking into actual IP Addresses or anything of that sort as the site will simply redirect to root/uk or root/us subfolders upon the user's selection on the index page. What kind of a unique parameter would I have incorporate in the db or php?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column in the database display_content, make it a [EMUN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) and set the values to 'britain','usa','all' then make the adjustments in your code to check for Britain/USA. you can either choose to display all, Britain or USA.

Comment: Great! I have most of the content set i.e. the checkboxes and their verification. I'm not sure how to pull the Enum values from the database and add to them. For example:
$sql = "INSERT INTO display_content";
$sql .= " SET title='$title', content='$content' " works fine for regular stuff. What would I do to add an on checkbox value to a particular Enum item? if the Enum column is called country and the following countries are selected:
[x]US
[x]Britian
[x]France
then
SET country=???

I can't find any reference on dealing with this data type through PHP.

Comment: I'm guessing the same syntax would apply when I pull the actual content and append to it something like Where id='$id' and then country='...' to make it work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting problem.  Because although it's language oriented, it's not actually I18N related - you're talking about deny access to content based on a language preference, not displaying localized content.

Here's one idea: use a permission model

- Create two permissions such as "read-enUS-content" and "read-enGB-content"
- Based on the user's selection, grant them the correct permission for the length of their session (which you can persist if you wish via cookies or user prefs)
- It would then be the responsibility of the application to allow/deny the content based on their permissions.

Then the question becomes, how do you connect content to permissions?  There are a multitude of ways, but one approach is a bitmask column.

```
00
||
|+--- Read enUS bit
+---- Read enGB bit
```

Which might look like this when implemented

```
Articles
+----+---------+-----------------+
| id | content | read_perm_level |
+----+---------+-----------------+
|  1 | foo     |               1 |
|  2 | bar     |               2 |
|  3 | baz     |               3 |
+----+---------+-----------------+
```

This means that 'foo' is only readable by enUS, 'bar' is only readable by enGB, and 'baz' is readable by all.

But you could also do a full permission's table and connect the content to it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward model for this would be an associative table in your database.  You'd thus have:

```
paragraphs (paragraph_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, paragraph_text TEXT, ...) ENGINE=InnoDB;
paragraph_countries (paragraph_id INT UNSIGNED, country_code CHAR(2)) ENGINE=Innodb;
```

When saving the paragraph settings, perform these steps:

1. `BEGIN WORK` (to start a transaction)
2. `DELETE FROM paragraph_countries WHERE paragraph_id = ...`
3. (foreach checked country): `INSERT INTO paragraph_countries (...)`
4. `COMMIT` (to commit the transaction)

To select paragraphs relevant to the current country, simply `JOIN` to the associated table with the appropriate country code.